# Multi-Step Approval Process

Tags: administration, approval-process, configuration

I am exposing myself to Approvals for the first time ever (from scratch, at least).  I had an assumption about them that so far is proving wrong.  I would appreciate some guidance as I'm see no help that tells me there IS a way to DO this.

I want to have FOUR STEPS in an Approval process - but I want each step to be done by the same person/queue.  I do NOT want to reassign it (nor do I want the person at each step to have to assign it).

I've looked at various possibilities (User lookup on User record so I can auto-assign to "that user", like "Manager", except "that User" would be the SAME user) (Hierarchial Lookup)... I can't come up with an idea.

**I don't want the process to be tedious.**

- Start an Apprvoal
- Approver does four steps and marks them done as they go
- Final approval ends the process

I just need four things confirmed and/or done, before Approval is given on the Record and next steps can be taken.  I plan on updating date/time markers "per step" as they're done (that step in the Approval is accepted).

**Any thoughts?**  I have pigeonholed myself into Approvals, where the solution may be elsewhere.

Comment: I think we need more information on what the process is.  If the same person approves the same 4 levels, then why not just have one level of approval?  Why make him click "approve" 4 times?

Comment: The four steps needs to be confirmed they've been done, and I had thought having four steps in the Approval process would be fine, but if I have to worry about (re-)assigning who does each step and can't somehow automated it to be "them again", I'm apparently using the wrong solution.   CAN I put it all in one step?  Yes, but that's far from ideal.   :-/

Comment: I believe you are about to misinterpret approval steps as process steps (stages) in general

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For our needs here, due to the nature of SF Approvals, we are emulating a **"Workflow" system in the company's legacy "Synergy" database** using a Custom Object.

We plan to use SF Approval to START the process (when Approval is started, it creates a record in the "Processes" custom object... that object stores the progress made on "whatever is being done", and when it either finishes, or is rejected, the SF Approval is marked Approved or Rejected.

*Our company's legacy Synergy setup has about 50+ "workflows" to be recreated, and SF Approval is not appropriate for things that are anywhere from 1 to 12 steps each - it's just not as simplistic, but IS good for locking out a record until something gets done/approved/rejected.  :-)*

Answer (score 1):

According to your requirement, you need to **create 4 separate approval processes**, rather than single approval process with 4 steps.

> **Approach**

1. Create 4 approval processes.
2. Create a picklist field which will contain following values like (1st approved, 2nd approved, 3rd approved).
3. In the 1st approval process, you should update the picklist value to `1st approved` through workflow field update. **Be sure to select the checkbox "Re-evaluate Workflow Rules after Field Change"** ***(otherwise process builder's process will not fire)***
4. Now, create process builder process which will fire based on `1st approved=true` and will Submit for Approval for `2nd Approval` process.
5. Proceed this kind of same steps for rest of the approval processes.

> Process flow will be like this:

[image: Approval process chain]

Comment: This makes sense, thanks.  Did not consider that PB could create Approvals for me - picklist field and the rest already exist.  SHould work perfectly...........

Comment: if that solves your requirement, please accept so others may find this useful

Comment: I always do.  AM not working on this item at the moment. ;)   Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From the input it's not clear where you having issues? Setup the approval it's only setup.

If your problem is with reassign - then note, that in SF standard approval process you cannot block the reassign option. Meaning- current approver can always reassign it to any other user.